# How to terminate Quarkus Application after task finish

Tags: scala, quarkus

Our team use Quarkus framework, I need to create a project simply runs a task then exit itself.

I read the Quarkus document, and write the code in scala as below
The `EMRExecutionMonitor` is call in Main Aplication
`Quarkus.run(classOf[EMRExecutionMonitor], args: _*)`

Quarkus start up and I can see the logging
but Quarkus would not exit even I called Quarkus.asyncExit(0)
it just keeping running in console until I use Ctrl+C

I build project in Jar, and run as `java -jar quarkus-run.jar`

My expectation is when the logic finished in EMRExecutionMonitor, Quarkus application exit.

```
class EMRExecutionMonitor extends QuarkusApplication {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass)
    override def run(args: String*): Int = {
        logger.info("start EMR execution monitoring job")
        Quarkus.waitForExit()
        Quarkus.asyncExit(0)
        0
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [@QuarkusMain](https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#the-main-method) feature to execute your code within a main method.
The following example executes & terminates your code at the end.

```
@QuarkusMain
public class EMRExecutor {

public static void main(String... args) {
    Quarkus.run(EMRExecutionMonitor.class, args);
    Quarkus.asyncExit(0);
}
public static class EMRExecutionMonitor implements QuarkusApplication{

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Log.info("start EMR execution monitoring job");
        Quarkus.waitForExit();
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

The console output will print out the termination info:

```
2023-11-19 13:51:45,671 INFO  [sk.mal.EMRExecutor$EMRExecutionMonitor] (Quarkus Main Thread) start EMR execution monitoring job
2023-11-19 13:51:45,717 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) quarkus-test stopped in 0.039s
Process finished with exit code 0
```